# Symfony2 using Multiuser Bundle and Alice Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

on my webproject I've been using the Hautelook Alice Bundle (https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) to create my fixtures for dev and testing. For User Management I'm using the FOS UserBundle.
My data file looked somewhat like this and it used to work perfectly fine:

```
AppBundle\Entity\StaffDetail:
  staffdetail_{1..5}:
    prefix: <title()>
    first_name: <firstName()>
    last_name: <lastName()>

AppBundle\Entity\Staff:
  staff_1:
    username: admin@example.com
    plainpassword: password
    email: admin@example.com
    mandant: @mandant_1
    enabled: true
    role: administrator
    staffdetail: @staffdetail_1
  staff_{2..5}:
    username (unique): <safeEmail()>
    plainpassword: password
    email: <identity($username)>
    mandant: @mandant_1
    enabled: true
    role: administrator
    staffdetail: @staffdetail_<current()>
```

Now I'm trying to have different login mechanisms for different user groups (staff and customers), so I want to use the Rollerworks Multi User Bundle (https://github.com/rollerworks/RollerworksMultiUserBundle).

I have created a new bundle for customers and staff and set everything up. When using the application everything works just fine. But generating the fixtures does not work anymore.

In the data file just namespaces changed.

```
Users\StaffBundle\Entity\StaffDetail:
  staffdetail_{1..5}:
    prefix: <title()>
    first_name: <firstName()>
    last_name: <lastName()>

Users\StaffBundle\Entity\Staff:
  staff_1:
    username: admin@example.com
    plainpassword: password
    email: admin@example.com
    mandant: @mandant_1
    enabled: true
    role: administrator
    staffdetail: @staffdetail_1
  staff_{2..5}:
    username (unique): <safeEmail()>
    plainpassword: password
    email: <identity($username)>
    mandant: @mandant_1
    enabled: true
    role: administrator
    staffdetail: @staffdetail_<current()>
```

When I run the fixtures command (or run the tests which also execute the generate fixtures command) it looks like it's trying to just insert the values into the database without running the FOS UserBundle constructor for the entity first, as the password, username_canonical, etc are not set.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO staff (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_tok
  en, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, role, staffdetail_id, mandant_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["ad
  min@example.com", null, "admin@example.com", null, 1, "kbttb26978gkkcosk404wccgc4os8wo", null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, "a:0:{}", 0, null, "administrator", 22, 13]:
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username_canonical' cannot be null
```

I'm stuck with this for a few days now, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `usernameCanonical` to your fixture:

```
Users\StaffBundle\Entity\Staff:
    staff_1:
        usernameCanonical: <identity($username)>
```

This same for other staff entries. Your `User` probably have logic which fills it automatically based on username value.

Make sure that your `Users\StaffBundle\Entity\Staff` implements `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface` and `FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserListener` is called (it will call `updateCanonicalFields` and `updatePassword` before saving user).

Read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html#updating-a-user-object

Comment: I have already thought about that, and while this might work for fields like username_canonical or email_canonical, it won't work for the password which is encrypted from the plainpassword field.

Comment: Ahh so there is more properties not filled - you ned to show us your Entities.

Comment: Looks like setters are not called - it just fill directly provided properties

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Doctrine Listener for Fos User is not called: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/8f1fc2273b37c61ddcc1620abf4500320a23763e/Doctrine/UserListener.php read more here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/d5b28c367d393f9d9fbc48c4138b2a74d51c0c83/Resources/doc/custom_storage_layer.rst

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out later tonight. But my entity extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` which implements `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface`

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I solved it now by providing all the fields to the fixtures. Also the hashed password.